# Where do you set the OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.NamingStrategy in a unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using both ORMLite and Dapper in a project and would like standardized on the naming conventions used by both ORMs. In order to do this I'd like to set the NamingStrategy as such:

```
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.NamingStrategy = new OrmLiteNamingStrategyBase();
```

and a unit test to verify

```
public class BorrowerUnitTests : IDisposable    
{
    private readonly ServiceStackHost appHost;

    public BorrowerUnitTests()
    {
        //Set ORMLite to work with columns like ColumnLikeThis
        // OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.NamingStrategy = new OrmLiteNamingStrategyBase();

        appHost = new BasicAppHost(typeof(BorrowerServices).Assembly)
        {

            ConfigureContainer = container =>
            {

                container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
                    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigUtils.GetConnectionString("LoanOrigination:Default"), PostgreSqlDialect.Provider));

                container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<Repository, IRepository>();
                container.RegisterAutoWired<BorrowerDomainService>();
            }

        }
        .Init();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        appHost.Dispose();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestPostMethod()
    {
        var service = appHost.Container.Resolve<BorrowerServices>();

        BorrowerCreate request = new BorrowerCreate();
        request.FirstName = "Orm";
        request.LastName = "Lite";
        request.Email = "ormlite@servicestack.net";

        var response = service.Post(request);

        Assert.True(response.Id > 0, "Id retured from POST cannot be zero");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestGetMethod()
    {
        var service = appHost.Container.Resolve<BorrowerServices>();

        BorrowerGet request = new BorrowerGet();
        request.Id = 1;

        var response = service.Get(request);

        Assert.Equal("ormlite@servicestack.net", response.Email);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestPutMethod()
    {
        var service = appHost.Container.Resolve<BorrowerServices>();

        BorrowerUpdate request = new BorrowerUpdate();
        request.Id = 5;
        request.FirstName = "MyFirstName2";
        request.LastName = "MyLastName2";
        request.Email = "MyEmail@Example.com";

        var response = service.Put(request);

        Assert.True(response.FirstName == "MyFirstName2", "FirstName is noth equal");
    }
}
```

No matter where I put the NamingStrategy statement, I get a exception from the DialectProvider property of the OrmLiteConfig class, "You must set the singleton 'OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider' to use the OrmLiteWriteExtensions"

Where's the proper place to set this property?

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just assign it to the DialectProvider you're using, e.g:

```
PostgreSqlDialect.Provider.NamingStrategy = new OrmLiteNamingStrategyBase();
```

The `OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider` is a singleton that can either be set manually:

```
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = PostgreSqlDialect.Provider;
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.NamingStrategy = new OrmLiteNamingStrategyBase();
```

Or implicitly with the `new OrmLiteConnectionFactory()` constructor, which to run, needs to resolved from the IOC:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(...));
using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
{
    OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.NamingStrategy = new OrmLiteNamingStrategyBase();
}
```